# Return Binary Image Data from Laravel with Correct Content Type

Tags: php, laravel, http, response, mime

I have a Laravel controller that retrieves binary image data from some source like the database or an API and returns it as the response:

```php
class ExampleController extends Controller 
{

  // ...

  public function testImage(Request $request)
  {
    // This is a binary string not a stream or file handle
    $binaryImageData = $this->repository->getImage($request->query);

    return response($binaryImageData);
  }
}
```

However since Laravel returns a Content-Type header value of `text/html' when I open this in the browser the binary data is rendered as HTML.

I can't guarantee that I will have access to the correct content type for the image data.

So how would I go about detecting and returning the correct type?

Answer (score 2):

I think those methods can help :

**mb_detect_encoding**

(Detect character encoding.)

```
$encoding = mb_detect_encoding($binaryImageData, mb_list_encodings(), true);
```

**Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::getClientMimeType**

(Returns the file mime type.)

```
$mimetype = $binaryImageData->getClientMimeType();
```

**Example of response headers using content type ($mimetype) :**

```
      return response(Storage::get($file->path))
        ->withHeaders([
          'Content-disposition' => 'attachment; filename=' . $file->file_name,
          'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => 'Content-Disposition',
          'Content-Type' => $file->mimetype,
        ]);
```

Comment: This wont work. `$binaryImageData` is a string containing binary data, it doesn't have any methods. `getClientMimeType` appears to be a method of `UploadedFile`. To be clear, no file is being uploaded. I also don't understand why you would want to detect the character encoding of a binary string, whatever `mb_detect_encoding` detects is bound to be wrong since it's binary not text. I've added a comment to the code in my question since obviously it wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

After further research I have determined there is no Laravel specific way to detect the mime type of a binary string. However there is a generic PHP way:

```php
function detectMimeType(string $input)
{
    return (new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE))->buffer($input);
}
```

Also Laravel currently has [league/filesystem](https://github.com/thephpleague/flysystem) as a dependency, which in turn has [league/mime-type-detection](https://github.com/thephpleague/mime-type-detection) which provides it's own class based wrapper for the finfo. I would recommend to anyone who prefers `league/mime-type-detection` to require it explicitly in their projects `composer.json` file in case Laravel drops the requirement in the future.